# Speech corpora for VAD

Tags: dsp-core, speech-recognition, speech-processing, speech

I'm doing a student research project connected with VAD.
And I want to find speech corpora with added noise.
I found many references to the NIST Speaker Recognition Corpora. But unfortunately, all links on main site are already dead.

Maybe someone has this Corpora? Or someone can recommend a good Corpora with noise?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Most of those databases are paid for, you won't find them available for free. The licenses aren't too expensive, but they are non-zero cost.

Comment: You need corpus with speech or speech with noise. You could add noise on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the MUSAN corpus from the Kaldi people (Dan Povey, et al):

- [Corpus audio/text](http://www.openslr.org/17/)
- [Check the arxiv paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.08484v1.pdf)

> MUSAN is a new corpus of music, speech, and noise. This dataset is
>   suitable for training models for voice activity detection (VAD) and
>   music/speech discrimination. Our corpus is released under a flexible
>   Creative Commons license. The dataset consists of music from several
>   genres, speech from twelve languages, and a wide assortment of
>   technical and non-technical noises. We demonstrate use of this corpus
>   for music/speech discrimination on Broadcast news and VAD for speaker
>   identification.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant paper is

"The QUT-NOISE-TIMIT corpus for the evaluation of voice activity detection algorithms"

http://eprints.qut.edu.au/38144/

Noise database is available here

https://www.qut.edu.au/research/research-projects/speech-audio-image-and-video-technology-saivt

For speech instead of TIMIT you can take any public database, for example, librispeech:

http://www.openslr.org/12/

Answer (score 1):

Free speech dataset for VAD recorded in real environment with ground truth label:

refer: https://github.com/jtkim-kaist/VAD-Toolkit